# Entity framework 6 code first saving collection via foreign key relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Hi i'm having issues saving a collection to database which is related via a foreign key.

This is what i have.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to save the images and products like below.

```
 using (TestDbContext s = new TestDbContext())
            {        
                Product p = new Product() { ProductName = "test", Images = new List<Image>() {new Image{ ImageName="test"} } };
                s.Products.Add(p);
                s.SaveChanges();
            }
```

However, i get the following Error:

```
{"Invalid column name 'Product_ProductId'."}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Image](
        [ImageId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ImageName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Image] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ImageId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ImageId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Product]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ImageId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Image] ([ImageId])
GO
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: did you modify the column name in the database manually ?? check your database, what is the columnname of the FK to Product on Image table

Comment: nope i did not change it. I have updated my question with the SQL script used to create the tables

Comment: I'm confused now, the classes show that a product has multiple images, but in the database script you gave, image table is referred by product table, how did you create the database? generated using EF code first or create the database manually then create the class ?

Comment: no, the SQl code shows that i have a foreign key on product table which means that Product table references images. not the other way around...

Comment: product table references images, that means 1 image has many products, but in the classes it's the oppsite

Comment: I see! thanks for spotting lol. I totally messed this one up. O well its 4am here :(. I will correct this tomorrow. Thanks for the help mate, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to use the existing database, you need to remove this property from `Product` class

```
public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

and add this property on `Image` class,

```
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

then add following config on `OnModelCreating`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Image>().HasMany(i => i.Products).WithRequired().Map(m => m.MapKey("ImageId"));
```

and finally use it this way

```
var i = new Image() { ImageName = "test", Products = new List<Product> { new Product { ProductName = "test" } } };
s.Images.Add(i);
s.SaveChanges();
```